# How to logout from public key authentication - ssh

Tags: ssh

I am using key based authentication for ssh. When ever i try to login into the system it doesn't ask me for public key. It simply logs in, i just want to logout from this public key authentication. And when ever i need i will enable it. Can some one say me the way to logout from Public Key authentication. And How to set timeout for this public key authentication? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If from command line you can see your identity with

```
ssh-add -l
```

then you can remove it (i.e. make the agent to forget it), with

```
ssh-add -D
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a automatic timeout?

Comment: @karthick87: you can use `ssh-add -t number-of-secs`. It will ask for passphrase.

Comment: What is the default timeout?

Comment: There is not timeout (or infinite timeout). The man page of `ssh-add` say it is configurable, but cannot found where.

Comment: For the traditional `ssh-agent`, it is possible to set a default time out through a command line switch.  You'll probably find that `ssh-add` is talking to `gnome-keyring` though, and I don't think it has the facility to set a default time out for keys.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want a normal login/logout method? If yes, then remove the key in the remote machine. I think its in /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys then restart ssh daemon. Please let me know if that is correct.

Comment: No you are wrong. I just want to logout from the public authentication. So that after i close my terminal and if i open again, it should prompt for public key.